# What is the easiest way to draw a perfectly filled circle(disc) in assembly?

Tags: assembly, nasm, tasm

I'd like to draw a perfectly filled* circle(disc) in assembly in 320x200 mode with a 100 pixel radius. What's the quickest/easiest way?

(*: I mean a disc is perfectly filled when its color is e.g. constant white and has no black pixels in it.)

Comment: Draw the outline and then flood fill the circle. This isn't a graphics programming tutorial site, so read up on how to do those things and try to implement them yourself. If you run into a specific problem with the code you write, then ask a question about that.

Comment: Even simpler might be to trace only half of the circle's outline and mirror it horizontally.  That is, for each point `-x,y`, draw a horizontal line from `-x,y` to `x,y`.

Comment: Perfect to me means anti-aliasing on the edges.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If by quickest you mean the quickest to write, here a simple solution for DOS.

It doesn't use any DOS service but the exit one.
It is meant to generate a COM file (raw output with NASM is fine, just rename it with COM extension).

```
BITS 16

ORG 100h

push 0a000h           ;Video memory graphics segment
pop es

mov ax, 0013h         ;320x200@8bpp
int 10h


push 09h              ;Blue
push 159              ;cX
push 99               ;cY
push 60               ;Radius
call drawFilledCircle

;Wait for a key
xor ah, ah
int 16h

;Restore text mode
mov ax, 0003h
int 10h

;Return
mov ax, 4c00h
int 21h


;Color
;cX
;cY
;R
drawFilledCircle:
 push bp
 mov bp, sp

 sub sp, 02h

 mov cx, WORD [bp+04h]   ;R

 mov ax, cx              
 mul ax                  ;AX = R^2
 mov WORD [bp-02h], ax   ;[bp-02h] = R^2



 mov ax, WORD [bp+06h]
 sub ax, cx              ;i = cY-R
 mov bx, WORD [bp+08h]
 sub bx, cx              ;j = cX-R

 shl cx, 1
 mov dx, cx              ;DX = Copy of 2R

.advance_v:
 push cx
 push bx

 mov cx,  dx

.advance_h:
  ;Save values
  push bx
  push ax
  push dx

  ;Compute (i-y) and (j-x)
  sub ax, WORD [bp+06h]
  sub bx, WORD [bp+08h]

  mul ax                  ;Compute (i-y)^2

  push ax
  mov ax, bx             
  mul ax
  pop bx                  ;Compute (j-x)^2 in ax, (i-y)^2 is in bx now

  add ax, bx              ;(j-x)^2 + (i-y)^2
  cmp ax, WORD [bp-02h]   ;;(j-x)^2 + (i-y)^2 <= R^2

  ;Restore values before jump
  pop dx
  pop ax
  pop bx

  ja .continue            ;Skip pixel if (j-x)^2 + (i-y)^2 > R^2

  ;Write pixel
  push WORD [bp+0ah]
  push bx
  push ax
  call writePx


.continue:

  ;Advance j
  inc bx
 loop .advance_h

 ;Advance i
 inc ax


 pop bx            ;Restore j
 pop cx            ;Restore counter

loop .advance_v

 add sp, 02h


 pop bp
 ret 08h



;Color
;X
;Y
writePx:
 push bp
 mov bp, sp

 push ax
 push bx

 mov bx, WORD [bp+04h]
 mov ax, bx
 shl bx, 6
 shl ax, 8
 add bx, ax       ;320 = 256 + 64

 add bx, WORD [bp+06h]
 mov ax, WORD [bp+08h]

 ;TODO: Clip

 mov BYTE [es:bx], al

 pop bx
 pop ax

 pop bp
 ret 06h
```

It simply a common technique for writing plane figures given some parameters, it's called rasterization.

Given the center **C**(*x*, *y*) and the radius **R** of the circle, the algorithm is as follow

```
1. For i = y-R to y+R
1.1   For j = x-R to x+R
1.1.1     If (i-y)^2 + (j-x)^2 <= R^2 Then
1.1.1.1      DrawPixel(j, i)
1.1.1     End if
1.1   End For
1. End For
```

**This is not optimized for speed, at all!**
I indeed create multiple routine for the sake of clarity. 
Also I use the stack a lot.

**Note** `writePx` does not clip the coordinates!

---

If you want to speed up the things you need to be more specific on your requirement.
For example is the radius always fixed? If yes you can use a block of memory that encode a quarter of circle, something like this

```
0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1
0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1
0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1
0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
```

Where each digits may be a bit or a byte depending on your speed vs memory constraints.
You can then copy this block directly into video memory or use it as a template (kind of chroma key technique).
For printing the other three quarters of the circle simple play with the counters.

If the radius is not fixed you can boost the code above by

- Inlining the functions call
- Avoid the use of the stack as much as possible
- Don't compute the distance at every cycle but compute it from previous value using basic calculus.
- Compute more that one pixel at a time and combine writings.

Comment: Awesome. Thanks. This is what I was looking for. Many good ideas.

Answer (score -2):

Found this on how to draw a circle. Sorry, its not filled. Read the whole article here:
http://groups.csail.mit.edu/graphics/classes/6.837/F98/Lecture6/circle.html

```
    //Circle  
public void circleMidpoint(int xCenter, int yCenter, int radius, Color c)
{
    int pix = c.getRGB();
    int x = 0;
    int y = radius;
    int p = (5 - radius*4)/4;

    circlePoints(xCenter, yCenter, x, y, pix);
    while (x < y) {
        x++;
        if (p < 0) {
            p += 2*x+1;
        } else {
            y--;
            p += 2*(x-y)+1;
        }
        circlePoints(xCenter, yCenter, x, y, pix);
    }
}

    //pixel plotter

     private final void circlePoints(int cx, int cy, int x, int y, int pix)
{
    int act = Color.red.getRGB();

    if (x == 0) {
        raster.setPixel(act, cx, cy + y);
        raster.setPixel(pix, cx, cy - y);
        raster.setPixel(pix, cx + y, cy);
        raster.setPixel(pix, cx - y, cy);
    } else 
    if (x == y) {
        raster.setPixel(act, cx + x, cy + y);
        raster.setPixel(pix, cx - x, cy + y);
        raster.setPixel(pix, cx + x, cy - y);
        raster.setPixel(pix, cx - x, cy - y);
    } else 
    if (x < y) {
        raster.setPixel(act, cx + x, cy + y);
        raster.setPixel(pix, cx - x, cy + y);
        raster.setPixel(pix, cx + x, cy - y);
        raster.setPixel(pix, cx - x, cy - y);
        raster.setPixel(pix, cx + y, cy + x);
        raster.setPixel(pix, cx - y, cy + x);
        raster.setPixel(pix, cx + y, cy - x);
        raster.setPixel(pix, cx - y, cy - x);
    }
}
```